# Google calendar time zones when switching calendar

Tags: google-calendar

It seems that if you move an event with time zone information from one Google calendar to another, the time zone info is lost. But if you move it back to the original calendar again, the time zone info reappears! I am guessing what is happening is something like:

```
ADD TIME ZONE XYZ TO EVENT AAA

MOVE EVENT AAA TO CALENDAR ABC

UNDO MOVE EVENT AAA TO CALENDAR ABC
```

and the last two commands cancel each other out. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not what I'm seeing. When I move an event to a different calendar, the time zone is lost completely. Moving it back doesn't make any difference, the time zone is still gone.

I think this happens because calendars have their own time zones. Google must assume that when you move an event to a calendar, you want it to adopt the same time zone as the calendar itself.